# Original creation date of word document

Tags: 2007, content-type, word

I have a word document created in, say, July 10 2010.
When i upload it to sharepoint (say August 5, 2010) its creation date vaalue in sharepoint will be in Aug 5, 2010, and i can't find any trace of the original date (July 10). Is there a way to keep the original date? is is kept somewhere or is it completely lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still kept with the document, it's just not where you'd expect it to be.  When you open the document from the document library and view the metadata using the Document Information Panel, you'll get options to switch from: Doc Properties:Server (SharePoint), Doc Properties (Original Doc Properties), and Advanced Properties.  Within the Advanced Properties, you'll be able to view the original creation date.

A bit convoluted, but there may be solutions that take this data and post it as metadata to your list, if needed.