# Is original file creation date preserved after upload in Windows Explorer? (SP2013)

Tags: 2013, document-library

It is a common problem, that basic file properties like creation and last modified date and original author/last editor are lost during upload of files to SharePoint via Windows Explorer.

I read in a post about `SharePoint 2007' that the original creation and modified date are still stored in SharePoint and can be shown:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/5170/19145

> It's still kept with the document, it's just not where you'd expect it
>   to be. When you open the document from the document library and view
>   the metadata using the Document Information Panel, you'll get options
>   to switch from: Doc Properties:Server (SharePoint), Doc Properties
>   (Original Doc Properties), and Advanced Properties. Within the
>   Advanced Properties, you'll be able to view the original creation
>   date.

However I do not find a way to display those "Original Doc Properties" in my documents library in SharePoint 2013.

How can I do that`?
Is it a question of content type or library settings?